# DDD aggregate consist of recordі in multiple table but for business it does not matter

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate `Product` which consist of other small entities for example, product can have many `Tags`, where tag can be visible, hidden and has own icon. And  same for few more.

Historically we storing data in Sql database, so from data perspective it'll looks like separate tables for products and for tags, and tags will contain product id.

But from domain perspective we do not cate if it's separate tables or not, and for domain perspective each object simply should have a list of tag value object, not entities.

So question is, how to be with tag id?? I mean we need we probably need it to map with database, but from domain perspective we don't care about it as we will never update tags separately, and having that field in domain class can lead to some unpredictable results.

I see few possible solutions:

1. do not add id to domain entity and in data mapping layer simply delete all records by product id from tags table and insert again.
2. to have this id in domain object, but add comments and hide somehow to minimize it usage, to use only for transforming to data.

I know Ideally probably is to change database to some Document database, but it's not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

> But from domain perspective we do not care if it's separate tables or not, and for domain perspective each object simply should have a list of tag value object, not entities.

Be careful not to confuse your reporting needs with your domain dynamics.

An important check: are there any rules about changing tags that depend on other information in the Product? are there any rules about changing Project that depend on tags?

If not... then there's no particular reason that Tags need to be modeled as part of product.  The relationship between a Tag and a Product (or better: a ProductId) could be an entity in the domain with its own lifecycle, and managed completely separately from the core idea of product.

See [All our aggregates are wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hev65ozmYPI) (Mauro Servienti, 2019)

Comment: you mean I can treat `Tag` as a separate aggregate root, or separate entity but as a part of `Prodcut` aggregate root. And I'll never get command from FE to update some tag by id, I can get command like "product tags updated and list of new tags, but without ids". So as I understand it make no sense to treat `Tag` as entity or aggregate root as it'll never be used without product